# Do I have to declare both WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard

Is it enough to declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` or do I also have to declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`?  The Javadocs omit this important information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no permission is ever automatically granted

Comment: You don't have to set the read permission. Try `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` on `FileInputStream`

Comment: Wrote an answer, but now I clearly remember one of my applications where I never needed the read permission.

Comment: In fact the documentation clearly states that the write permission implies the read permission as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hi from the future. Could you link to where the documentation says that? All I found was this not very helpful documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @MiffTheFox It is written in [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) section of that doumentation: "Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` only exists as of Jelly Bean (Level 16). According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Permissions), all applications as of Jelly Bean have that permission, even without declaring it:

> Provides protected read access to external storage. In Android 4.1 by
>   default all applications still have read access. This will be changed
>   in a future release to require that applications explicitly request
>   read access using this permission. If your application already
>   requests write access, it will automatically get read access as well.
>   There is a new developer option to turn on read access restriction,
>   for developers to test their applications against how Android will
>   behave in the future.

So, you should declare it for future compatibility, but this might not be the source of your problem, unless you're using a Jelly Bean phone and set the developer option "Protect USB storage" option.

Comment: +1, I already found the source of my problem; of course it wasn't related to this.  Thanks!

Comment: -1 **This is not an answer to the question actually asked**.  The documentation clearly states that the write permission implicitly brings the read permission as well.  So there is no need to declare this to "future proof" apps which write; is is **only needed** for apps which desire **read-only** access.

Comment: First time I have seen a comment have more use than the post. @ChrisStratton is 100% correct.

Answer (score 20):

It's best to be explicit and declare both permissions, but declaring only `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will automatically add `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your APK at build time.

You can use the command `aapt dump badging` on an APK to see that Android considers usage of the write permission to *imply* that you also want read permission.

Here's some output from aapt for an APK of mine where I declared *only* `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my manifest:

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
  'requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
```

Comment: Why would it be best to declare both? As of Marsh, you have to request run-time perms, and having to do it for both read and write makes no sense, especially when write gives read implicitly.

Comment: We did not add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for a recent Google warning for Loan apps for this permission. We only needed `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. And surprisingly, the App was rejected as the bundles were automatically adding `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to bundle manifests. Not even normal APK merge manifest had it!

Comment: @sanister Yes we did, the runtime `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission 
 that was added in Kotlin code in just 1 place to download a file using `DownloadManager`, while everywhere else we were using Scoped Storage. As a result, when Bundle was getting generated, it was adding the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for safety automatically in the manifest file during merger. We have now completely moved remaining such code to scoped storage