# Android M (API 23+) runtime storage permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

In my app, i need to read from and write to external storage.

In Android M, do I need to prompt the user for both permissions `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?
or is asking for one of them is enough since they both fall under the **Storage** permission group?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942400/do-i-have-to-declare-both-write-external-storage-and-read-external-storage

Comment: thanks, but i need to know if it works with Android M (API 23+) with the new runtime permissions.

Comment: Why not just ask for both if you're effectively going to use them both?

Comment: yup you need to ask for permissions as you cant say which will be asked first but once its granted you dont need to ask for another permission as both fall in same group

Comment: Look at runtime permission groups.  http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en 

If you ask for one permission and user accepts it, you will have permission to all group permissions.

Comment: Thanks Ragaisis. Indeed your link answered my questions. I only need to ask for one permission and i will be granted the other one automatically. This way i will avoid prompting the user for a permission request a second time where i don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ragaisis, this [blog post](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) has the answer to my question

Quote from the blog post:

> If any permission in a Permission Group is granted. Another permission
>   in the same group will be automatically granted as well