# getting an image path from a ImageButton?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageButton` and when the user click it he will open the gallery and select image and show it in `ImageButton` by `onActivityResult()` method.
My question is how to get the path image after `ImageButton` clicked and store the path in sql.

Comment: see the accepted answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344154/how-to-get-path-of-selected-image-from-gallery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get path of selected Image from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344154/how-to-get-path-of-selected-image-from-gallery)